# JSON Post in Android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, getjson

I am developing an app where I have to log in using username and password, so that an invalid user can't log in and a valid user can. Users can't register, a unique id and password will be given to the it.

Hence, I have used JSON POST method for this purpose.

But I am unable to post data. Whatever id & password i am giving, getting default error message.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> 01-02 11:31:38.047: V/Response(2888):
>   {"Login":"false","error":{"email":"Please enter a valid Email
>   address.","password":"Please enter your password."}}

Complete code is posted below.

```
TextView tvIsConnected;
EditText username;
EditText password;
Button login;

Driver driver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }

 // add click listener to Button "POST"
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public static String POST(String url, Driver driver){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("username", driver.getUsername());
        jsonObject.accumulate("password", driver.getPassword());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}

private boolean isConnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;  
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.login:
        if(!validate())
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://dfl.tulieservices.biz/webservices/userOperation/user_login");
    break;
}
}

public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        driver = new Driver();
        driver.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
        driver.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

        Log.v("USERNAME", username.getText().toString());
        Log.v("PASSWORD", password.getText().toString());

        return POST(urls[0],driver);




    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.v("Response", result);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}

private boolean validate(){
    if(username.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(password.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;    
}
```

}

Comment: the id is not registered or not exists

Comment: What's the issue exactly? As you have shown, you are already getting response from the server.

Comment: i am getting response from the server which is default error message in case id and password is wrong. Problem is same error message is coming out when i am giving valid id and password @PareshMayani

Comment: If you're certain that you send the correct id & password then the problem must be on the server side, the server code is what's relevant and not the Android code. Debug on server side and 1. make sure that you recieve correct id/password 2. see why it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

remove your 7 step and try in public static String **POST** method

```
TextView tvIsConnected;
EditText username;
EditText password;
Button login;

Driver driver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }

 // add click listener to Button "POST"
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public static String POST(String url, Driver driver){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("username", username.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("password", password.getText().toString());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);


            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: already using public static String POST method...Same problem

Comment: i said that remove your 7 step in your post method that is dont use httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Comment: did exactly what you told. still no luck for me. @user2675669

Comment: i think i have found the problem. data passing like: {"password":"111111","username":"driver100@dfl.com"}              But it should be like below format:    {"values":{"email":"testone@gmail.com", "password":"111111","user_type":"driver"}}'  Can you please help me on this? @user2675669

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable time. problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try below at 3rd step

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    //jsonObject.accumulate("username", driver.getUsername());
    //jsonObject.accumulate("password", driver.getPassword());
    jsonObject.put("username", driver.getUsername());
    jsonObject.put("password", driver.getPassword());
```